# How to convert the projections of the lines to any usable segmentation information?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, plot, image-segmentation

I have been reading about automatic text line recognition in Matlab and although there are many advanced methods to do this every paper mentions that the simplest way of detecting text lines is via  horizontal projections. So I decided to try this method for myself.

I am very new to this and have hit a brick wall, I have reached a level beyond which I do not know how to proceed. This is what I have achieved so far:

I'm trying for a system that is language independent and only interested in text lines, so I chose Arabic text:

[image]

I used the function `radon` to get the projections.

```
img = rgb2gray(imread('arabic.jpg'));
[R, xp] = radon(bw_closed, [0 90]);
figure; plot(xp,R(:,2)); title('at angle 90');
```

This is the plot(projection)

[image]

So clearly the 5 peaks represent the 5 lines detected but how do I go from here to segmenting the original document?

Can anyone help me beyond this point? All the papers I read make no mention of how to proceed from this step, they just say that from the projections we have our detected lines.

What I'm asking is how, from the plot data can I tell matlab what is the line of text and what is the gab between lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
r = R(:,2);
r=r(92:391); % your image region
blank = r < 3; % region without text
[labeled, n] = bwlabel(blank);
C = regionprops(labeled, 'Centroid');  % find the centers of blank regions
for i=1:length(C)-1
    subplot(length(C)-1,1,i)
    imshow(img(C(i).Centroid(2):C(i+1).Centroid(2),:));        
end
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That explains a lot but can you please tell me where you got the image region and threshold values from? ``r=r(92:391);`` and ``blank = r < 3`` can you please tell me on how you got these values?

Comment: @FarazKhan I used radon(im2bw(img), [0 90]); 91 is the 1st position that the radon value is nonzero, and 392 is the last one. But there is some effect similar with zero-padding, so I remove the border by selecting the region from 92 to 391. r=2 is the minimum value between the 5 curves, so i used r<3

Comment: Thank you. I understand the ``r=r(92:391);`` but is it really necessary? I mean the same result could be produced without this step right? Also looking at the plot I cannot understand how you picked up that the ``r=2`` is the minimum distance between the curves. Did you pick that up from the plot? Can you tell me how please. Thank you

Comment: my plot is different from what you showed in your question (and i don't know what is bw_closed in your code). So I just use [R, xp] = radon(im2bw(img), [0 90]);
figure; plot(xp,R(:,2)); title('at angle 90'); to produce a different plot, you can have a try and observe the small values at valleys

Comment: without cropping the image, you may get an error, because the center of blank may be out of range of your original image. If you use imhist instead of radon transform at the beginning, you won't face such a problem

Comment: I get an error when I tried to implement this myself. ``Index exceeds matrix dimensions.`` in line ``imshow(img(cent(k).Centroid(2):cent(k+1).Centroid(2),:));`` and it only prints 4 of the lines. Also I know I alreadys elected your answer but can you please tell me why you are only selecting the 'y' coordinate of the Centroid? I tried it with the x-coordinate and it does not work. Isnt the centroid the xy coordinate of the centre of the object? Then why does it only work with the y-coordinate? Many Thanks

Comment: Faraz, you need to make sure that the length of r won't exceed the row number of img. In the coordinates, y axis refers to the row in a matrix, while x is the column.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45590/discussion-between-faraz-khan-and-lennon310)

Comment: Can we get python version of this method?